# Removing JS array element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've currently got a set of javascript functions that are used to set intervals and clear them.
The issue is; the intervals are stored in an array (**`intervals[]`**)

```
config: {
    settings: {
        timezone: 'Australia/Perth,',
        base_url: location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '' + ((location.pathname) ? location.pathname : ''),
        api_url: '/api/'
    },
    intervals: []
}
```

There are two functions that work with that array:
The first being the interval setter:

```
interval_set: function(time, name, callback) {
        this.config.intervals[name] = setInterval(callback, time);
    }
```

and the second being the interval clearer

```
interval_clear: function(name) {
        if (this.config.intervals[name]) {
            clearInterval(this.config.intervals[name]);
            this.debug('Interval: "' + name + '" cleared.', 1);
        } else {
            this.debug('No interval: "' + name + '" found.', 1);
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is I need to remove said interval from the intervals array, although as you can see - it isn't set with a specific key.

The interval array looks like this:

```
Array[0]
    derp: 1
```

I've tried using `splice()` but that doesn't seem to work. What would you suggest I do? Should I store it in the array with an index?

Thanks :)

Comment: Array: numeric index; Object: string key. Looks like you mixed them up.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for pointing that out, will fix my stupidity now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is just:

```
delete this.config.intervals[name];
```

Incidentally, you aren't really using `intervals` as an `Array` here, you're just using it like a regular `Object`. So it would be more correct for its starting value to be {} instead of [].

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I don't know why I didn't try this. Thanks! Edit: Will change it properly from object to array.